# Неактивный Scroll HTML

Tags: html, css, javascript

Собсно сабж, как показать на странице неактивный вертикальныйй скрол, если материала недостаточно для активизации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю вам подойдет:

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

Вот более [подробная информация](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow-y), вот еще [англоязычное исследование](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html) по теме.

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет overflow-y: scroll;

Обратите внимание на ресурс, предложенный kemerov4anin. Очень часто выручает :)